# ¿Por qué no logro obtener solo dos decimales cuando muestro los resultados por consola en el último else del código?

Tags: javascript, condiciones, else

En este simulador no logro obtener decimales de solo dos dígitos en el último else del código. Sé que es utilizando la propiedad toFixed( ) pero he hecho pruebas en diferentes sitios y poder mostrar el Promedio de los positivos con solo 2 decimales, e incluso guardar el resultado que se muestra en ese último else del código (Promedio de los positivos) en una variable antes y no logro dar con que cuando insertes algunos números, los decimales no sean mas de 2. Gracias de antemano.

```
let sumaNeg = 0;
let contPos = 0;
let sumaPos = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    let num = parseInt(prompt("Ingresar un número: "));
    console.log(num);
    if(num === 0){
        continue;
    }
    else if(num < 0){
        sumaNeg += num;
    }
    else{
        contPos++;
        sumaPos += num;
    }
}

if(sumaNeg === 0){
    console.log("No se ingresó ningún negativo");
}
else{
    console.log("Suma de los negativos: " + sumaNeg);
}

if(contPos === 0){
    console.log("No se ingresó ningún positivo");
}
else{
    console.log("Promedio de los positivos: " + sumaPos / contPos);
}
```

Comment: si quieres decimales porque aplicas un parseInt()? cambialo a Number() que pertimitira numeros ya sea enteros o decimales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De tanto darle e investigar y probar por horas, encontré la solución. Estaba implementado mal el método toFixed propio de Javascript. En relación a mi caso, lo que hice fue declarar una variable que denominé promedioPositivos y moví la división que estaba en el último else del código y lo almacené en la variable. Luego, simplemente sustituí la división que allí estaba por dicha variable y allí es cuando le implementé el método toFixed, el cual para poder implementarlo de manera correcta lo agregué con un punto inmediatamente después de la variable en el último console.log del código y entre paréntesis le coloqué el número 2 para que el resultado arrojara sólo 2 decimales (en mi caso 2 pero entre los paréntesis pudiera ir la cifra que se requiera). ¡Voilá!

```
let sumaNeg = 0;
let contPos = 0;
let sumaPos = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    let num = parseInt(prompt("Ingresar un número: "));
    console.log(num);
    if(num === 0){
        continue;
    }
    else if(num < 0){
        sumaNeg += num;
    }
    else{
        contPos++;
        sumaPos += num;
    }
}

let promedioPositivos = sumaPos / contPos

if(sumaNeg === 0){
    console.log("No se ingresó ningún negativo");
}
else{
    console.log("Suma de los negativos: " + sumaNeg);
}

if(contPos === 0){
    console.log("No se ingresó ningún positivo");
}
else{
    console.log("Promedio de los positivos: " + promedioPositivos.toFixed(2));
}
```